# How to properly use state hook with useSelector?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I have two `react-select` elements in my app and the 2nd one should be populated with options based on the selection of the first. It works but when the Select #1 is cleared, #2 is not being reset.
So I decided to implement `useState` to help me update/reset the options for Select #2 but it's acting wonky. Am I missing something or is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
export const dataViewPage = ({
  getData,
  loadLocationsByType,
  classes,
}) => {

  const [stateValue, setStateValue] = useState('');
  const [store, setStore] = useState('');
  const [storeOptions, setStoreOptions] = useState([]);  // Constant to populate options for Select #2
  const locationType = 'store'; 
  const Input = styled('input')({ display: 'none' });

  /* Returns locations in selected state in array of objects with location_id and name */
  const locations = useSelector((state) =>
    getFilteredLocations(state, stateValue, locationType)
  );

  useEffect(() => { // Fetches locations data on state change
     stateValue &&
      loadLocationsByType({ locationType: locationType, state: stateValue });
  }, [stateValue, loadLocationsByType]);

  useEffect(() => { // Sets store options in expected format
    if (locations) {
      setStoreOptions(
        convertObjArrayToSelectOptions(locations, 'location_id', 'name')
      );
    } else { // Reset if no state is selected?
      setStoreOptions([]);
    }
  }, [locations, stateValue]);
}

  /* Main input functions */
  const handleStateChange = (e) => {
    let stateEntered = e ? e.value : '';
    setStateValue(stateEntered);
  };

  const handleStoreChange = (e) => {
    let selectedStore = e ? e.value : '';
    setStore(`T${selectedStore}`);
    console.log(selectedStore);
  };

return (
    <div>
                <div>
                  <p>Enter or select state</p>
                  <Select
                    classes={classes}
                    placeholder="Select state"
                    options={states}
                    onChange={handleStateChange}
                    isClearable
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <p>Select store:</p>
                  <Select
                    options={storeOptions}
                    isClearable
                    onChange={handleStoreChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <label>
                  <Input type="submit" />
                  <Button
                    onClick={handleSubmit}
                  >
                    View data
                  </Button>
                </label>

    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: It sounds like you've got a problem with your state getting out-of-sync, but that will be hard to diagnose without seeing the rest of the code (e.g. what is `getFilteredLocations` doing? What about `loadLocationsByType`? `useSelector` - are you using redux too? What does the redux store look like?). Could you create a minimal repro on StackBlitz (or similar)?

Comment: Certainly! I actually wondered about that while posting, I will create one later today. In general though, this is the way `useSelector` and `useState` would be expected to be used?

Comment: They can certainly be used together, I don't know that there's an "expected" way to use them though, it always depends on circumstance.